# What's wrong with my merge sort implementation?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

```
// merge operation for merge sort
private static void merge(int[] a, int left, int middle, int right) {
    int[] temp = new int[right - left + 1];        
    int leftCrawler = left, rightCrawler = middle;
    int currentIndex = 0;

    while (leftCrawler < middle && rightCrawler <= right) {
        if (a[leftCrawler] < a[rightCrawler])
            temp[currentIndex++] = a[leftCrawler++];
        else
            temp[currentIndex++] = a[rightCrawler++];
    }

    while (leftCrawler < middle)
        temp[currentIndex++] = a[leftCrawler++];

    while (rightCrawler <= right)
        temp[currentIndex++] = a[rightCrawler++];

    // copy temp into a
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        a[i] = temp[i];
}

private static void mergeSort(int[] a, int left, int right) {
    if (right > left) {
        int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, left, middle);
        mergeSort(a, middle + 1, right);
        merge(a, left, middle, right);
    }
}

public static void mergeSort(int[] a) {
    int left = 0, right = a.length - 1;
    mergeSort(a, left, right);
}
```

So, I thought that the issue might be with my merge operation, however I tested it on the following array  `int[] a = {2, 5, 7, 15, 8, 9, 10}` with `left = 0`, `middle = 4` and `right = a.length - 1` and the merge operation does what it needs to successfully.

I have compared my implementation of mergeSort to those on various websites and I can't spot a difference. My mergeSort will not successfully sort the array. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 errors in your code:

- the merge loop does not include the element at `a[middle]` because you use `leftCrawler < middle` instead of:

  ```
    while (leftCrawler <= middle && rightCrawler <= right)
  ```
- the second loop `while (leftCrawler < middle)` must also be changed to:

  ```
    while (leftCrawler <= middle)
  ```
- the loop to copy from `temp` back to `a` uses an incorrect index into `a`. It should be:

  ```
        // copy temp into a
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            a[left + i] = temp[i];
  ```

Note that the first error is rooted in the noxious convention used here where `right` and `middle` are included in the slices instead of excluded. Excluding the right boundaries allows for simpler code without any error prone `+1`/`-1` adjustments.

Here is a modified version:

```c
// merge operation for merge sort
private static void merge(int[] a, int left, int middle, int right) {
    int[] temp = new int[right - left];        
    int leftCrawler = left, rightCrawler = middle;
    int currentIndex = 0;

    while (leftCrawler < middle && rightCrawler < right) {
        if (a[leftCrawler] < a[rightCrawler])
            temp[currentIndex++] = a[leftCrawler++];
        else
            temp[currentIndex++] = a[rightCrawler++];
    }

    while (leftCrawler < middle)
        temp[currentIndex++] = a[leftCrawler++];

    while (rightCrawler < right)
        temp[currentIndex++] = a[rightCrawler++];

    // copy temp into a
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        a[left + i] = temp[i];
}

private static void mergeSort(int[] a, int left, int right) {
    if (right - left >= 2) {
        int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, left, middle);
        mergeSort(a, middle, right);
        merge(a, left, middle, right);
    }
}

public static void mergeSort(int[] a) {
    mergeSort(a, 0, a.length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be with your copy:

```java
    // copy temp into a
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        a[i] = temp[i];
```

What you probably want is (notice the `left + i`):

```java
    // copy temp into a
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        a[left + i] = temp[i];
```

(Your test did not detect the issue, since `left` was 0.)

Comment: I made the change and my input array remained exactly the same. I acknowledge that this change was necessary but I'm still not sorting the array.